# Why not to modify lists in for loops in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I've been reading a book "Python Crash Course 2nd Edition" and saw this phrase:

> A for loop is effective for looping through a list, but you shouldn’t
> modify a list inside a for loop because Python will have trouble
> keeping track of the items in the list

'You shouldn’t modify a list inside a for loop because Python will have trouble keeping track of the items in the list' That confused me. I don't understand what this means. That's basically it.

To sum up, my question is **Why not to modify lists in for loops in Python?**